# Create Docker image from digest files placed in local directory

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I have sonar scanner digest files on my local machine as shown below[image]

I am create a docker image from file sha256__124f1a7cc754368005d84f5825bdaac66889ba74a719d60de8525b9f26770b6a

How can i do so?
Here is content of JSON File

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 5603,
      "digest": "sha256:124f1a7cc754368005d84f5825bdaac66889ba74a719d60de8525b9f26770b6a"
   },
   "layers": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 2754729,
         "digest": "sha256:8e402f1a9c577ded051c1ef10e9fe4492890459522089959988a4852dee8ab2c"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 239,
         "digest": "sha256:4866c822999cc5862e60f784434873bd291ef9a7ac6e9199a5d1d19eea22fe17"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 70716050,
         "digest": "sha256:ec484ea07ed1e4b3d2c8bb6ffb98d668fc1602607ced25e40a0d3649c875af12"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 17621683,
         "digest": "sha256:a1f6d7c584422524106a7ef517ee2ec8843feb4cbc3c7978abe374a8002643db"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 561709,
         "digest": "sha256:5975595d2cc6865dc1bf2bb8f86dfa8f2486613919babc5e575fc3c705c907df"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you `COPY` the files you need into your custom image?

Comment: That looks like a disassembled image and layers in something close but not quite an OCI layout. What are the contents of the manifest.json? Please post formatted text, not pictures, because I don't want to manually transcribe digests into an answer.

Comment: Hi David, Do i need to copy all files or last digest file

Comment: Hi Bmitcht, I have added the content of JSON file

Answer (score 0):

May you try

```
FROM imagename@124f1a7cc754368005d84f5825bdaac66889ba74a719d60de8525b9f26770b6a
```

Comment: I don't have imagename